# Using decorators with MapReduce mapper/reducer functions?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce

I'm trying to wrap my mapper/reducer functions with something like:

```
def log_exceptions_to_sentry(sentry_id, raise_exception):
    def decorator(fn):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return fn(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception, e:
                client = Client(sentry_id)
                client.captureException(
                    exc_info=sys.exc_info())
                if raise_exception:
                    raise e
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

and so my mapper/reducer functions look like:

```
@log_exceptions_to_sentry(SENTRY_ID, False)
def my_mapper_fn(item):
    logging.info(item)
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Without the decorator, I'd find `INFO` logs of `item`. But if I put the decorator, it seems the mapper/reducer functions don't get called at all.

I was hoping to make it easy to log any errors my functions might have so I can fix them, as trying to track down MapReduce via AppEngine's logs is almost impossible.

I could wrap the entire function body with `try ... except` block, but a decorator would be cleaner.

Comment: Don't say `raise e` only say `raise`, otherwise the exception is thrown with a new traceback.

Comment: Don't put a : behind the decorator-call, this is a syntax-error

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have an issue with the decorator structure. In partuclar, I think you want to replace

```
try:
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
```

with

```
try:
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
```

I'm missing some of the functions to test this, but you can see simplified decorator examples here if you want to run one: http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/

Try something like this to make sure your code works, then try the more complicated parameterized version after:

```
sentry_id = id
raise_exception = 1

def basic_decorator(function):
    global sentry_id, raise_exception
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        try:
            function(*args,**kwargs)
        except Exception, e:
            client = Client(sentry_id)
            client.captureException(exc_info=sys.exc_info())
            if raise_exception:
                raise
    return wrapper

@basic_decorator
def my_mapper_fn(item):
    logging.info(item)
```

To parameterize `sentry_id` and `raise_exception`, wrap the decorator inside another decorator. The idea is that when the basic decorator is defined, `sentry_id`, `raise_exception`, and `function` will be defined ahead of time and enclosed within its scope. This should look something like

```
def log_exceptions_to_sentry(sentry_id,raise_exception=1):
    def basic_decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                function(*args,**kwargs)
            except Exception, e:
                client = Client(sentry_id)
                client.captureException(exc_info=sys.exc_info())
                if raise_exception:
                    raise

        return wrapper
    return basic_decorator

@log_exceptions_to_sentry(SENTRY_ID,RAISE_EXCEPTION)
def my_mapper_fn(item):
    logging.info(item)
```

Comment: So, in your example, how do you get a return value from `x = my_mapper_fn(item)`? In your case, x will always be None because you're not returning the value of `fn(*args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: @snapshoe, you're correct. I was trying to show the `logging.info` example from the question, which doesn't use a return value. Not all functions in Python use a return statement.

Regardless, the decorator structure works so that you can define whatever base function you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `SENTRY_ID` or `Client` is, since you didn't post it. So I made up my own. Using your code exactly, everything appears to work as expected. I'm not sure what you're seeing that isn't working right.

```
SENTRY_ID = 1
class Client(object):
    def __init__(self, sentry_id): pass
    def captureException(self, **kwargs):
        print('captureException, ', kwargs['exc_info'])

def log_exceptions_to_sentry(sentry_id, raise_exception):
    def decorator(fn):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return fn(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                client = Client(sentry_id)
                client.captureException(
                    exc_info=sys.exc_info())
                if raise_exception:
                    raise e
        return wrapper
    return decorator

def fn(item):
    logging.debug(item)
    logging.info(item)
    logging.error(item)

@log_exceptions_to_sentry(SENTRY_ID, False)
def my_mapper_fn(item):
    logging.debug(item)
    logging.info(item)
    logging.error(item)
    return 1

@log_exceptions_to_sentry(SENTRY_ID, False)
def my_mapper_fn2(item):
    raise Exception()

logging.basicConfig(
    level = logging.INFO,
    format = '%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s',
    #format = '%(message)s',
)

x = fn({'a':1})
print(x)
x = my_mapper_fn({'b':2})
print(x)
x = my_mapper_fn2({'c':3})
print(x)
```

Output:

```
INFO:root:{'a': 1}
ERROR:root:{'a': 1}
None
INFO:root:{'b': 2}
ERROR:root:{'b': 2}
1
captureException,  (<type 'exceptions.Exception'>, Exception(), <traceback object at 0x1813cf8>)
None
```

Comment: Hmm I did try this, and it works on the console as well, it just doesn't work as expected when running via AppEngine MapReduce library. Also, mapper/reducer functions `yield` values, and not `return` them.